# Is the function using python list comprehension, stateless?

Tags: python, functional-programming

Below is the function `count_leaf`, that appends mutable list `branch_counts`, which is not stateless.

```
def count_leaf(tree):
    if is_leaf(tree):
        return 1
    branch_counts = list()
    for b in tree:
        branch_counts.append(count_leaf(b))
    return sum(branch_counts)
```

Below is the program that uses list comprehension.

```
def count_leaves(tree):
    if is_leaf(tree):
        return 1
    else:
        branch_counts = [count_leaves(b) for b in tree]
        return sum(branch_counts)
```

Is the function `count_leaves` using list comprehension `[count_leaves(b) for b in tree]` purely functional?

Comment: Where do you think you see state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is, because there is no state being mutated. The line `branch_counts = [count_leaves(b) for b in tree]` can be interpreted as a simple binding (like a let statement in Haskell or Lisp), as there are no further reassignments or mutations.

Additionally, you could reformat it like this to make it clearer:

```
def count_leaves(tree):
    return 1 if is_leaf(tree) else sum([count_leaves(b) for b in tree])
```

Comment: Ok so, list comprehensions & generator expressions help us do functional programming ):

Comment: Yes they're a frequent idiom in functional programming. Why the sadface @overexchange?

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can pretend that it is, but be careful. List comprehentions create or mutate variables in the surrounding scope. (in ipython console):

```
In [1]: x
NameError: name 'x' is not defined

In [2]: [x for x in range(10)]
Out[2]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

In [3]: x
Out[3]: 9
```

So if you had something like

```
x = "foo"
[x for x ...]
```

x will not be "foo" any more.

Note that this doesn't happen when using generator expressions:

```
In [4]: y
NameError: name 'y' is not defined

In [5]: (y for y in range(10))
Out[5]: <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f55b7861e10>

In [6]: y
NameError: name 'y' is not defined

In [7]: y = "foo"

In [8]: y
Out[8]: 'foo'

In [9]: (y for y in range(10))
Out[9]: <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f55b7877410>

In [10]: y
Out[10]: 'foo'
```

edit: Forgot to actually answer the question clearly. No, it is not stateless, it mutates state locally.

Comment: "No, it is not stateless, it mutates state locally." Maybe it introduces bindings, but strictly speaking his function *is* stateless.

Comment: yes, it does not mutate any variables in the enclosing scope and it does not modify it's arguments. But the same is true for the first function as well.

Comment: It's not because of this line: `branch_counts.append(count_leaf(b))`. This is mutating the state referred to by the `branch_counts` variable.